# issue with unmute button java android

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a simple click counter android app, sound is played when a button is clicked and the count is also saved when leaving the count screen and then returning to it.

I have encountered a problem with the mute button.  When I click it, it mutes the whole application rather than just that particular gui screen (activity).

1. First issue is that the mute button mutes the sound for the whole app, and I only need to mute for that activity.
2. Second issue is that when you click mute button and come out of the screen, then go back, then try to unmute -  it does not unmute the sound.

Was thinking the resolution to this is that we take the mute button out of the SharedPreferences save instance state - if this is possible...

Here is my code so far, if you can guide me on how to achieve the above that would be great.  Thanks.

```
public class wazeefa extends Activity {

    //Count Button
    TextView txtCount;
    ImageView image;
    Button btnCount;
    Button wmute;
    Button wreset;
    public static int count = 0;
    SharedPreferences app_preferences;
    MediaPlayer mpButtonClick;
    AudioManager audioManager;
    public static boolean mutestatus = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // The activity is being created.
        setContentView(R.layout.wazeefa);


        audioManager =
                (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        //SAVE COUNT
        app_preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefscount", MODE_WORLD_READABLE);


        count = app_preferences.getInt("count", 0);

        txtCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wcount);
        txtCount.setText("This app has been started " + count + " times.");

        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);

        txtCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wcount);
        txtCount.setText("This app has been started " + count + " times.");

        //Button SOUND AND COUNT
        mpButtonClick = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bubble);
        //RESET Button
        wreset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wreset);

        txtCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.wcount);
        txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));

        btnCount = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wclick);

        wmute = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wmute);

        btnCount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                count++;
                if (count > 50) count = 0;
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.duroodimage);
                if (count > 0) image.setImageResource(R.drawable.duroodimage);
                if (count > 9) image.setImageResource(R.drawable.zikrimage);
                if (count > 39) image.setImageResource(R.drawable.duroodimage);
                txtCount.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                mpButtonClick.start();
            }
        });

        wreset.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                count = 0;
                image.setImageResource(R.drawable.duroodimage);
                ;
                txtCount.setText("0");
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
                editor.putInt("count", count);
                editor.commit();
            }
        });


        wmute.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (!mutestatus) {
                    mutestatus = true;
                    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL);
                    audioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, true);
                    Log.v("'test....", "" + mutestatus);
                } else {
                    mutestatus = false;
                    audioManager.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_NORMAL);
                    audioManager.setStreamSolo(AudioManager.STREAM_VOICE_CALL, false);
                    Log.v("'test....", "" + mutestatus);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        // save count value here

        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
        editor.putInt("count", count);
        editor.commit();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saving the preferences on the application level, make it Activity specific, i.e. Implement mute functionality for the activity not the application.

**Edit**

See your objective is some what to mute and unmute (loquent) the audio, *Preferences can be saved in three ways.*

***1) Preferences can be retrieved only by a single activity.***
2 )Preferences can be shared and retrieved among all activities within the application.
3)Preferences can be shared and retrieved through all applications on the device.

In your case, Saving Activity-level preferences:

```
SharedPreferences prefs=getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor=prefs.edit();
        editor.putString("pref 1", "some text");

        editor.commit();
```

We get a SharedPreferences object by calling getPreferences(int mode) method which takes an integer value as a parameter, the mode value can be one of the following:

Context.MODE_PRIVATE (0): a file creating mode that makes the created file only accessible by applications with the same user ID (access the file from the same application context, will desctribe later).
Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE (1): file mode makes the file readable from other applications.
Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE (2): file mode allows other applications to write to the file.
Then we get an instance of SharedPreferences.Editor and write the preference value with editor.putString(String key, String value) method.
shared preferences allows you to insert preferences using the following methods:

```
editor.putBoolean(String key, boolean value).
editor.putFloat(String key,float value).
editor.putInt(String key, int value).
editor.putLong(String key, long value)
editor.putString(String key, String value)
```

Then we call edit.commit() to save the preferences to the file. commit returns a boolean indicating the result of saving, true if successful and false if failed.

Reading preferences values:
To read preferences values:

```
SharedPreferences prefs=getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String val=prefs.getString("pref 1", "some text");
We use sharedpreferences.getString(String key, String defaultValue) (or get boolean/float/int) to return the value stored with a specific key or defaultValue if not found.
```

[Source](http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-developmentusing-preferences/)

Comment: Hi, I am new to Java, could you give me some more detail on how to do this?