# turn off sound for whole application android

Tags: java, android

I am quite new to android and currently working on a quiz app in which I have sounds that play when users are using the app. I have a switch button in my settings activity in which should toggle sounds for the application on and off.
I have implemented some logic but it ain't working yet. I have exhausted the much I know and I need some help.

**style.xml**

```
 <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:soundEffectsEnabled">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppThemeMute" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:soundEffectsEnabled">false</item>
    </style>
```

**MyApplication.java**

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static int sTheme;

    public final static int THEME_SOUND_ON = 0;
    public final static int THEME_SOUND_OFF = 1;



    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    public static void changeToTheme(Context context, int theme) {
        sTheme = theme;

        switch (sTheme) {
            default:
            case THEME_SOUND_ON:
                context.setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
                break;
            case THEME_SOUND_OFF:
                context.setTheme(R.style.AppThemeMute);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**SettingsActivity.java**

```
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Switch mSoundSwitch;
    private  Switch mAdsSwitch;
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        // handling switch button
        mSoundSwitch = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.soundSwitch);
        mSoundSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
if (isChecked) {
    sharedPreferences =  getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("sound", true);
    editor.apply();
    // Change Whole App Theme
    MyApplication.changeToTheme(getApplicationContext(), MyApplication.THEME_SOUND_ON);
} else {
    sharedPreferences =  getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("sound", false);
    editor.apply();
    MyApplication.changeToTheme(getApplicationContext(), MyApplication.THEME_SOUND_OFF);
}
            }
        });

        sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        boolean isChecked = sharedPreferences.getBoolean("sound", true);
        mSoundSwitch.setChecked(isChecked);

    }

}
```

For now the switch button works perfectly with `sharedPreferences`. However, the sounds are not muted when the button is toggled.

Comment: I think you have t recreate your current activity may work. use `recreate()` in before ending of your `changeToTheme` method

Comment: or if this not work for you then check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14031399/issue-with-unmute-button-java-android)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895882/mute-the-global-sound-in-android

Comment: I thinks setting theme will not work. You should get your music service in place of your changeToTheme() method. There you can control your application music with music service object.

Answer (score 1):

```
private void mute() {
    //mute audio
    AudioManager amanager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, true);
}

public void unmute() {
    //unmute audio
    AudioManager amanager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    amanager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, false);
}
```

This two function can handle the audio `mute` and `unmute` quite well.

You can simply give toggle / switch to `mute` or `unmute` according to user `preference`.

Comment: how do i create the global variable?

Comment: This will mute the notification stream for all apps.

Comment: This will mute entire device notification sounds. Better to program to control in your application level.

Comment: AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC worked for me. However, do i need to worry about the deprecation warning of setStreamMute?

Comment: This will mute audio for all apps.